# Erro ao reconhecer SSH Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

Galera seguinte estou com um problema grave,nunca aconteceu esse problema comigo de ssh no linux,de um dia para o outro a chave ssh parou de funcionar,tentei repetir o processo para fazer uma nova mas mesmo assim nada aconteceu,e sempre que eu tentava conectar com o meu repositório dava a mensagem que vou deixar no print,se alguém conseguir me ajudar por favor estou com medo que isso aconteça no meu trabalho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está realmente tentando fazer SSH com o usuário "git" no host "bitbucket.org", confere isso?

Comment: Sim,sempre funcionou e do nada parou e da esse log e pede uma senha

Comment: Vc deve adicionar sua chave ssh ao bitbucket, aparentemente vc mudou sua chave e ele não reconhece mais.

Comment: mas eu fiz isso e mesmo assim pede a senha :s

Answer (score 1):

Esta conta **git@bitbucket.org** é para ser utilizada pelo cliente do **git** e não para acesso remoto:

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as XXXXXXXXXX.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Neste caso a chave SSH do meu usuário é a mesma que está cadastrada no Bitbucket, ele a identifica me reconhece mas me bloqueia, por razões óbvias, o acesso.

Porém, ao fazer o mesmo com o `sudo`, você estará usando outro usuário, mais precisamente o *root* e então...

```
$ sudo ssh -vv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
...
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
...
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (18.205.93.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Ele não identifica chave e muito menos o *host*, daí pedirá para que você o adicione (no *root*) e como não há chave, pedirá a senha do usuário "git".